# Why VS2015 intellisense shows error on C++11 user defined literals (UDL)

Tags: eclipse, c++11, visual-studio-2015, c++14, g++4.9

The below code can be compiled and run, but VS2015 intellisense shows error. g++ & eclipse has the same issue (compiled & run but shows error)

Does anyone know how to fix it? I tried searching on google but hopeless. 
The error is a little annoying.. :-)

```
#include <iostream>
#include <thread>
#include <chrono>

using namespace std;
using namespace std::literals;
using namespace chrono_literals;

int main()
{
    this_thread::sleep_for(5s);
    cout << "test \n";

    return 0;
}
```

Error message: *"Invalid suffix 's' on integer literal"*

Thanks a lot!

Comment: Are you using PCH in your project? Only with that we were able to reproduce the problem on our end...

Comment: What do you mean by PCH?  I just created a new console project in VS2015

Comment: Sorry, I mean Precompiled Headers. They are enabled by default in the console project template; although I was thrown off by the lack of the usual "#include <stdafx.h>" in your example above.

Answer (score 1):

You should add some `#include` statements and `namespace` references:

```
    #include <iostream>
    #include <chrono>
    #include <thread>

    int main()
    {
        using namespace std::literals::chrono_literals;

        std::this_thread::sleep_for(5s);
        std::cout << "test \n";

        return 0;
    }
```

In your code, the compiler is not been told to use namespace `std`. The 5s does not work without `std::literals`

Comment: Intellisense still shows error with : 
    using namespace std::literals;
    using namespace std::chrono_literals;

Comment: It does not work. I guess it's because of some settings in VS2015 intellisense.

Comment: Yes, I have reproduced your observation. I had to resort to  `std::this_thread::sleep_for(std::chrono::seconds(5));`

Comment: @BrianPham Basically, Intellisense is stupid. If the compiler finds no errors, I tend to ignore it :)

Comment: Looks like a bug, we'll be looking into it. @melak47 - if you see more issues in VS2015 please send them in through the smile or Connect.

Comment: @LukaszMendakiewicz I do, it's just that IntelliSense and VC++ seem to always be "out of sync" when it comes to language features - so I don't really bother looking at IntelliSense errors anymore. I do like the auto completion very much, though :)